# Reference Request: Evaluation Relative Bound 0 to Differentiation

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

In Kato, *Perturbation Theory of Linear Operators*, Chapter 4, Section 1, Example 1.8, pp. 192-193, it is shown that for all absolutely continuous functions $u: (a, b) \to \mathbb{C}$ , $a < b$ finite, that also satisfy $u \in L^2(a, b)$, and for all $c \in (a, b)$, we have:

$$ \forall \, \epsilon > 0, \, \exists\,  M = M(\epsilon), \quad \vert u(c) \vert \leq \epsilon \Vert u^{\prime} \Vert_{L^2(a, b)} + M \Vert u \Vert_{L^2(a, b)};$$

i.e. the evaluation-at-$c$ operator has relative bound $0$ to the differentiation operator.

I believe that I have adjusted the proof to allow $u$ in $\mathcal{H}^1(\mathbb{R}) = \mathcal{W}^{1, 2}(\mathbb{R})$, the space of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ functions whose first (distributional) derivatives are also $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, where of course $(a, b)$ is replaced by $\mathbb{R}$. [Recall by the Sobolev Embedding Theorem that in $1$ dimension, $\mathcal{H}^1$-functions have continuous representatives, so the left-hand-side makes sense.]  There is a fidget for the non-finite domain, and a fidget by approximating $\mathcal{H}^1(\mathbb{R})$ functions in $\mathcal{H}^1(\mathbb{R})$ norm by Schwartz functions, but one may simply adapt the proof of Kato.

That said, this adjustment is clear enough that it is almost surely not original (assuming it is correct, of course).  I would like to believe that someone has written it up, or proven it by another method (rigorously enough for a pure-math paper, I hope), so that I could cite it and not bog my paper down with details.

> **Question:** Is the statement that for all $u \in \mathcal{H}^1(\mathbb{R})$, for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$,
>   $$ \forall \, \epsilon > 0, \, \exists\,  M = M(\epsilon), \quad \vert u(c) \vert \leq \epsilon \Vert u^{\prime} \Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})} + M \Vert u \Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}, \tag{*}$$
>   anywhere in the literature?  [Or a counterexample, of course!]

Comment: All the functions in $\mathcal{H}^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ are absolutely continuous.

Comment: You're right.  There's still the boundedness issue, but that's *much* easier.  Thanks.  There may not be much need left for the question, but I'll see.

Comment: You're welcome. As an outline: $u^{2}(c)-u^{2}(a)=\int_{a}^{c}u(x)u'(x)dx$ gives the existence of $\lim_{a\rightarrow\pm\infty}u^{2}(a)$ because $uu'\in L^{1}$. Those limits must be $0$ or $u\notin L^{2}$. Then you can apply Cauchy-Schwarz to $\int_{\mathbb{R}}(\epsilon u)(\frac{1}{\epsilon}u')dx$.